# Set specific data & time for repeat interval using cordova Local notification & ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, localnotification

Could anyone tell how set date and time for corodova local motification?

**Example:** 
For daily notification alert i want set date and time. Is it possible in local notification.?

**Sample code:**

```
$cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: 'Title here',
        text: 'Text here',
        every: 'day'
      }).then(function (result) {
        // ...
      });
    };
```

Regarding code, How to specify date and time for repeat interval? Plz help me to find out correct solution.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/luxflux/ionic-hello-world/tree/master/plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification

Its right there in their 'Using the plugin' section. Also, plenty of tutorials if you google a bit.